# Firebase limits

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I intend to develop an simple chat application inheriting the funtionalities of FCM. I would like to know the limits imposed over as it may restrict myself of implementing certain tasks. I would also like to know the number of connections at a given instant and the limit on number of messages could be send from a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any limitations regarding an app which uses a Firebase database. If we are speaking about pricing list, it's true there is a free plan, and if want to stay in this plan, you need to have less than `100 Simultaneous connections`, less than `1GB stored` and less than `10GB/month GB downloaded` according to [Firebase pricing list](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, thats really helpful. However what was that 1GB and 10GB storage limit? Would it be for the single user?

Comment: No, this not for a single user, this is for your entire application. And remebmber, even if you are using `the free plan`, you'll also be able to use `Analytics, App Indexing, Dynamic Links, Invites, Remote Config, Cloud Messaging, Performance Monitoring, and Crash Reporting services`.

Comment: i assume from your response that no limit for messages were placed but the limit for data storage is limited for 1GB. This 1GB that we speak of will be overiding the previously stored after it exceeds?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are no limitations for messages. The only limitation is for data storage, which is 1GB. No messages will be overridden after your storage limit is exceeded. Remember to use `Analytics` to see your storage status.

Comment: could you please tell me about Firebase Monthly active users limit @Alex ?

Comment: First of all Jay, this is not how things are working in this community. There is not correct to say that an answer is helpful, to accept it and than to change the accepted answer while no newer or better answer arrived. If you have a new question like the last one, just post a new fresh question, so me or other users can answer it. The last question is not related with the first one. Hope you reconsider accepting my answer.

Comment: sorry for the inconvience