# Firebase Android retrieve specific child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrRuV.png)

I have this code to retrieve my data and it does print out all my data in my logcat [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwlhU.png) , but I only want to grab (Annotation_City:) and print it to the device.  I've tried other stack questions and answers but still haven't figured it out :) thank you if you can help! :)

```
public void AllLocationMarkers() {
        grabMarkersFromDb = new Firebase("***");
        grabMarkersFromDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    Log.d("Locations updated", "location: " + location + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, change this line:

```
String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();
```

with this:

```
String location = (String) locationSnapshot.child("Annotation_City").getValue();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome it helped :) thank you.  If i can ask another question.  When a child gets added into my firebase it prints all the Annotation_City's again.  How can i get it to only print the new Annotation_City that got added

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked. So if you think that my answer helped you as you said, please consider accepting it. Because the second question is not related with the initial one, please post another question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Have never considered excepting answers aha.  How do i do so?

Comment: To accept an answer, check the colored checkmark next to the answer. It will turn it from grey to green.

Comment: It is saying I can't until I get a certain amount of reputation :(

Comment: You cannot give a +1 but you can accept the answer. This is how you can accept it. Take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390333/firebase-limits/44390524). See the green checkmark?

Comment: Awesome, got it :)